# How to get an error-code from a VB component into (serverside) JScript

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I have an plain-old asp web site that makes a call to a method in a dll written in VB 6. This method sets an error code in the VB Err Object if something goes wrong. Now I want to access that error code and description set in the Err object from a javascript (where I do the call to the dll method). First: is it possible? Second: if it is possible, how can I do that? Thanks in advance!

My first idea was:

```
Function MyFunc()
{
  var obj = Server.CreateObject(“MyDll.MyClass”);

  try
  {
    obj.MyMethod();
  }
  catch(error)
  {
    // Here I want to get the error code and description from the VB Err object
  }
}
```

However, when I try this, the error I get is wrong. (I tried to make a test-app which receives the same error.)  I get an error-code which isn't the same in JavaScript as in VB.

Anyone know how this aught to be done?

/L

Answer (score 1):

In your MyClass, add a property that holds the error info when an error event occurs, then you should be able to look at obj.MyErrorCode and find out what you need.

Comment: Okey. That could possibly be a workaround.
But it feels like it should be a more direct way.